ERROR - Failed to execute task ' ti' (KeyError: ' ti' in Apache Airflow)
I have been getting the following error (repeatedly) in Airflow 2.9.0 after upgrading from 2.2.0:
2024-05-07T11:10:43.522+0000] {local_executor.py:139} ERROR - Failed to execute task ' ti'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/executors/local_executor.py", line 135, in _execute_work_in_fork
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py", line 49, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 114, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 422, in task_run
    ti.init_run_context(raw=args.raw)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 3307, in init_run_context
    self._set_context(self)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py", line 127, in _set_context
    set_context(self.log, context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py", line 274, in set_context
    flag = cast(FileTaskHandler, handler).set_context(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/providers/microsoft/azure/log/wasb_task_handler.py", line 89, in set_context
    super().set_context(ti, identifier=identifier)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py", line 219, in set_context
    local_loc = self._init_file(ti, identifier=identifier)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py", line 500, in _init_file
    local_relative_path = self._render_filename(ti, ti.try_number)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py", line 290, in _render_filename
    return str_tpl.format(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: ' ti'

I used Airflow 2.2.0 before and there everything was still working fine without any errors or warnings. After the update to 2.9.0 and upgrading the database (using airflow db migrate --to-version="2.9.0"), I started receiving this error. This error also seemingly results in the scheduler crashing. The webserver is still accessible though.
Airflow is being run inside a docker container with the following base image: apache/airflow:2.9.0-python3.11

So far, I have already tried to set 'provide_context'=True in the default args and to specific PythonOperators.
Also note that the key where the key error occurs has a space in it (' ti'), which seems weird to me.
Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Edit 1: Even when Airflow does not have any DAGs loaded, it still has the same error. Which makes me believe that it has something to do with the database. I use a postgresql database for the metadata.
Edit 2: It seems like Airflow runs as long as no DAGs are running. However, if I execute any DAG it crashes immediately with the specified error.

I had the same issue and it turned out to be an issue with the log name.
Take a look at the log file format. New format should be something like this:
log_filename_template = dag_id={{ ti.dag_id }}/run_id={{ ti.run_id }}/task_id={{ ti.task_id }}/{%% if ti.map_index >= 0 %%}map_index={{ ti.map_index }}/{%% endif %%}attempt={{ try_number }}.lo
You may need to clear any active tasks first as they may be stuck with old file name and it won't process.

I just happened to figure this out, came back to post and it seems you already did. Thanks for the help. For the record, this format can be found in your airflow config and it uses Jinja template language.
